# Rails 4 images in public folder are not loading on Apache development

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails. I am working on a sample application for social networking. I have managed to upload the profile picture of users manually (By copying the image uploaded to /tmp/image to the public folder- public/images/tmp/image) and saved the path to db as avatar_url.

In the profile view I used

```
<%= image_tag(@userinfo.avatar_url, :alt=>"Avatar image")%>
```

and getting the picture when running on the rails server.

But after that I have deployed the app in apache with passenger in the development environment by setting **RailsEnv development**. After that the images are not loading. I tried to go to **myip:80/public/images/tmp/image**, and it gives **Routing Error**.

After searching on the web, I found that adding `config.serve_static_assets = true` in **production.rb** will solve the problem in production. But no use for me because it also stated that the static files will serve in development by default. For confirming the problem again, I started the rails server and opened localhost:3000/profile, image is there and not getting the image in myip:80/profile.

So do I need to add any other config. Or am I not supposed to do that in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution for my problem. Just sharing here.

The problem was actually because of permission issues. The picture will be created in a root temp directory on the form submission. Then I copied the image form the temp folder to the public folder. Hence it has only read permissions. After I deployed it, the image gets returns 403 forbidden error.

I used,

```
FileUtils.chmod 775, target
```

to set the permission. After that it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

The option `config.serve_static_assets = true` tells rails to serve the static assets for your application, but that job should really be left to Apache.

Your issue sounds more related to your Apache configuration than rails.

I would take a look at a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to configure Apache and Passenger to make sure your environment is setup correctly.

Anything in the public folder should be served by the web server. However myip:80/public/images/tmp/image is not a valid path. You would need to also have a filename at the end with an extension.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Actually I got the path of the uploaded image via **<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile>.path**. I just appended this path to public/images, and copied the image using **FileUtils.cp_r**. I used myip:80/public/images/tmp/**image** in the question as an alias to temporary file names such as RackMultipart20150304-28665-1e2a5g0.png. And I used that tutorial for configuring Apache.